# Can't create an array of input size in solidity

Tags: arrays, ethereum, solidity

I am trying to input a number with a function and create an array of given size - code & error below.

```
struct Product {
        uint PId;
        string PName;
        string Brand;
        uint[] quant_clicks;   //This array is supposed to store no. of clicks for each piece of product, 
                              //so its length will be the inputted quantity
        SCSection[] SChain;
    }

p.quant_clicks = uint[quant];  //When product is being created, array of input size must be created
                              //to store clicks for each piece (part of a function taking quant & other info as input)

TypeError: Integer constant expected.
        p.quant_clicks = uint[quant];
                              ^---^
```

Answer (score 0):

In Solidity, you cannot create arrays with a predefined size that initializes all elements to a specific value (such as zero). Solidity does not support the creation of arrays with a pre-filled default value for elements like Python's NumPy does. An alternative approach would be to declare it as dynamic initially, and in the function you could create another fixed array, and use a loop to set its value & add it to the global dynamic one.